# Laravel How to Add new value to Array

Tags: html, laravel, controller

i have codes about create and update at same time in my Controller file, when i create a new data it should also update a json array column in my User Table

```
    $rumah = Rumah::create($validatedData);

    $updateData = [
             'lihatAlamat' => json_encode($rumah->id),
             'editAlamat' => json_encode($rumah->id)
             ];
    auth()->user()->update($updateData);
    return redirect('/rumah');
```

So the problem with this when i create a data, it doesn't add array data but overwrite whole array inside lihatAlamat and editAlamat column

Example problem like this:

> lihatAlamat = ["1","2"]

> editAlamat = ["1","2"]

when i create data it becomes:

> lihatAlamat = 3

> editAlamat = 3

how to add new id number inside array

Comment: been a while since I last worked with Laravel & PHP but if I recall correctly in PHP you add to an array with array_push().
See https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use this instead:

```
$updateData = [
         'lihatAlamat' => [$rumah->id],
         'editAlamat' => [$rumah->id]
         ];
```

Hope this solve your problem.

Comment: it still doesn't work, it still overwrite my column with new value

Comment: This is my lihatAlamat and editAlamat Columns in my user table
      $table->json('lihatAlamat')->nullable();
      $table->json('editAlamat')->nullable();

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

well, i found my own answer

```
$rumah = Rumah::create($validatedData);

//convert json to array
$lihatAlamat = json_decode(auth()->user()->lihatAlamat);

//work same like above           
$editAlamat = json_decode(auth()->user()->editAlamat);

//insert id to array
array_push($lihatAlamat, $rumah->id);
array_push($editAlamat, $rumah->id);

//query update
auth()->user()->update([
'lihatAlamat' => $lihatAlamat,
'editAlamat' => $editAlamat
]);
return redirect('/rumah');
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi are you trying to update these two (lihatAlamat ,editAlamat) columns values  or you want to add old values + new values to combine.

if i have to to this is would use belongsToMany relationship  with pivot table and used sync or async with values so it would be easy to use.
But as of now you can use this

In model u can use mutator and accesors

```
protected function lihatAlamat(): Attribute
{
    return Attribute::make(
        get: fn ($value) => json_decode($value),
        set: fn ($value) => json_encode($value),
    );
}

protected function editAlamat(): Attribute
{
    return Attribute::make(
        get: fn ($value) => json_decode($value),
        set: fn ($value) => json_encode($value),
    );
}
```

Then in controller

```
$lihatAlamat = Auth::user()->lihatAlamat;        
$editAlamat = Auth::user()->editAlamat;

$lihatAlamat[] = $rumah->id
$editAlamat[] = $rumah->id

auth()->user()->update([
'lihatAlamat' => $lihatAlamat,
'editAlamat' => $editAlamat
]);
```